# Why are EPS files generated by gnuplot rotated 90 degrees?

Tags: eps, gnuplot

I have an EPS file generated by gnuplot. I used the code:

```
#set term post enh color
#set out '1.eps'
```

The EPS file viewer in gsview is horizontal. However, when I include it in my paper the graph is rotated 90 degrees (vertical)

I tried `set term post enh color port`, it doesn't work.

However, I found the following code can be used with LaTeX:

```
#set term post enh color eps
#set out '1.ps'
```

then use gsview to convert the PS file to EPS. It will be displayed horizontally in LaTeX (but rotated 90 degrees in gsview)

How can I get the EPS file such that it is rotated 90 degrees in both?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) This question has very little to to with TeX, and in its current form is likely to be closed. Please include a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to show us how you are including graphics, so we can make sure that it's a problem with gnu plot rather than your LaTeX code.

Answer (score 6):

Your first line `set term post enh color` says you want a PS file, while the second line, `set out '1.eps'` - that you want an EPS file.  Gnuplot uses different aspect ratios for PS and EPS output.

Use this:

```
set term post enh color eps
set ou "1.eps"
```

Here  is the result of this Gnuplot file

```
set term post enh color eps
set ou "1.eps"
plot x
set ou
```

and TeX file

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{1}
\end{document}
```

EPS file:

[image]

DVI file:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `set terminal postscript portrait` on Gnuplot, as you have said, rotates 90 degrees. There are three orientation related options in postscript terminal: landscape, portrait, and eps. Usually, `eps` option gets orientation right for both LaTeX and gv. If gv rotates the figure in 90 degrees, then configuration for gv should be changed, the orientation settings to `Automatic`.